# How can I track many blobs in occlusion, Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to develop an algorithm which tracks two hands. I need to handle the occlusion problem.  I have used the CvBlobs for this.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: you'll need to try something and put it here so other users accept to help you and even understand the problem that you're facing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some machine learning algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Try `cvStartFindContours()` and `cvFindNextContour()`

Found a few good links:

OpenCV HAND DETECTION code: http://download.andol.info/hsv.cpp

[color object tracking in openCV keeps detecting the skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985375/color-object-tracking-in-opencv-keeps-detecting-the-skin)

Hand gesture: http://www.andol.info/hci/895.htm

```
//VERSION: HAND DETECTION 1.0
//AUTHOR: ANDOL LI@CW3/18, Live:lab
//PROJECT: HAND DETECTION PROTOTYPE
//LAST UPDATED: 03/2009

#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;
/* 
--------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    CvSeq* a = 0;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
        if(!cvQueryFrame(capture)){ cout<<"Video capture failed, please check the camera."<<endl;}else{cout<<"Video camera capture status: OK"<<endl;};
    CvSize sz = cvGetSize(cvQueryFrame( capture));
    IplImage* src = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 3 );
    IplImage* hsv_image = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 3);
    IplImage* hsv_mask = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1);
    IplImage* hsv_edge = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1);

    CvScalar  hsv_min = cvScalar(0, 30, 80, 0);
    CvScalar  hsv_max = cvScalar(20, 150, 255, 0);
    //
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvMemStorage* areastorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvMemStorage* minStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvMemStorage* dftStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* contours = NULL;
    //
    cvNamedWindow( "src",1);
    //cvNamedWindow( "hsv-msk",1);
    //cvNamedWindow( "contour",1);
    //////
    while( c != 27)
    {
        IplImage* bg = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 3);
        cvRectangle( bg, cvPoint(0,0), cvPoint(bg->width,bg->height), CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0 );
            bg->origin = 1;
        for(int b = 0; b< int(bg->width/10); b++)
        {
            cvLine( bg, cvPoint(b*20, 0), cvPoint(b*20, bg->height), CV_RGB( 200, 200, 200), 1, 8, 0 );
            cvLine( bg, cvPoint(0, b*20), cvPoint(bg->width, b*20), CV_RGB( 200, 200, 200), 1, 8, 0 );
        }

        src = cvQueryFrame( capture);
        cvCvtColor(src, hsv_image, CV_BGR2HSV);

        cvInRangeS (hsv_image, hsv_min, hsv_max, hsv_mask);
        cvSmooth( hsv_mask, hsv_mask, CV_MEDIAN, 27, 0, 0, 0 );
        cvCanny(hsv_mask, hsv_edge, 1, 3, 5);

        cvFindContours( hsv_mask, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0) );
            CvSeq* contours2 = NULL;
            double result = 0, result2 = 0;
        while(contours)
        {
            result = fabs( cvContourArea( contours, CV_WHOLE_SEQ ) );
            if ( result > result2) {result2 = result; contours2 = contours;};
            contours  =  contours->h_next;
        }
        if ( contours2 )
        {
            //cout << "contours2: " << contours2->total << endl;
            CvRect rect = cvBoundingRect( contours2, 0 );
            cvRectangle( bg, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height), cvPoint(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y), CV_RGB(200, 0, 200), 1, 8, 0 );
            //cout << "Ratio: " << rect.width << ", " << rect.height << ", " << (float)rect.width / rect.height << endl;
            int checkcxt = cvCheckContourConvexity( contours2 );
                //cout << checkcxt <<endl;
            CvSeq* hull = cvConvexHull2( contours2, 0, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
            CvSeq* defect = cvConvexityDefects( contours2, hull, dftStorage );
            if( defect->total >=40 ) {cout << " Closed Palm " << endl;}
            else if( defect->total >=30 && defect->total <40 ) {cout << " Open Palm " << endl;}
            else{ cout << " Fist " << endl;}
            cout << "defet: " << defect->total << endl;

            CvBox2D box = cvMinAreaRect2( contours2, minStorage );
            //cout << "box angle: " << (int)box.angle << endl;
            cvCircle( bg, cvPoint(box.center.x, box.center.y), 3, CV_RGB(200, 0, 200), 2, 8, 0 );   
            cvEllipse( bg, cvPoint(box.center.x, box.center.y), cvSize(box.size.height/2, box.size.width/2), box.angle, 0, 360, CV_RGB(220, 0, 220), 1, 8, 0 );
                //cout << "Ratio: " << (float)box.size.width/box.size.height <<endl;
        }
            //cvShowImage( "hsv-msk", hsv_mask); hsv_mask->origin = 1;
            //IplImage* contour = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 3 );

        cvDrawContours( bg, contours2,  CV_RGB( 0, 200, 0), CV_RGB( 0, 100, 0), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
            cvShowImage( "src", src);
            //contour->origin = 1; cvShowImage( "contour", contour);
            //cvReleaseImage( &contour);

        cvNamedWindow("bg",0); 
        cvShowImage("bg",bg); 
        cvReleaseImage( &bg);




        c = cvWaitKey( 10);
    }
    //////
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();

}
```